# Instantaneous/transient short in un-energized circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, current-measurement

While extending a branch circuit in my basement, I discovered a transient short on the unenergized circuit. I eventually isolated the problem to a dehumidifier plugged into this circuit.

With the dehumidifier unplugged, I put my ohm meter across the line and neutral blades of the plug and get an instantaneous reading between 50-70 Ω, but it goes to infinite immediately. This is repeatable only on this device, so I'm confident it's not a problem with my multimeter or its operator. Successive readings appear to grow smaller and smaller each time.

My question is purely academic, since I don't care to chase this kind of fault on a device that is meant to run unsupervised.

Would a faulty capacitor in the primary cause this behavior? I'm having a hard time getting my head around the fundamentals. I doubt what I'm seeing is dissipation of the tiny, tiny current introduced by the meter, right? Is the meter causing a capacitor to discharge some tiny, residual voltage into a short? I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

Your multimeter is likely passing a current into the Class-X safety capacitor that sits across the live and neutral in the device. The multimeter measures this flow of current through the device as if it were a resistance, until the point where the capacitor is charged, at which point it acts as a DC block and the multimeter senses it as an open circuit.

Comment: And the capacitor holds some of that charge, which is why "readings appear to grow smaller" each time.  Understanding that the current is smaller, not the apparent resistance.